# Adding buttons to spreadsheets in .NET (VSTO)

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, excel-interop

Using VSTO or some related technology, is it possible to programmatically embed a button in a cell of an Excel worksheet, and configure it to call a C# function when it is clicked?

How?

Thanks.

Comment: A button cannot be embedded in a cell -- buttons "float". The best you can do is align it with a cell at design time.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically add a button? How would that be triggered? And would the C# it calls be in some add-in? This sounds like a complex setup, and I am not clear on why you would want to do that; why not simply have a VSTO add-in, and a menu or ribbon which makes the function available from any worksheet?

Comment: @Jay:  I can live with that.  Any tips on how to float a button above my worksheet?

@Mathias:  Yes, I would like to add the buttons dynamically and the C# callbacks will be in an add-in.  The purpose of my add-in is to help the user lay out 'forms' in a spreadsheet, and I would like some of the forms to incorporate buttons.

Comment: @McCoolBeth: did my answer help any? If not, what is missing?

Comment: @Mathias: I need this to work from an Add-In that does not depend on any specific document.  Your answer may be applicable to add-ins as well as to document customizations.  I will attempt to ascertain its applicability in a couple of day, when I return to the relevant project.

Answer (score 12):

With a VSTO document customization (i.e., a Workbook with .Net code attached), you can add and remove controls at runtime to the Worksheets of the project. The following code illustrates the idea:

```
 public partial class Sheet1
 {
     private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {
        var button = this.Controls.AddButton(10, 10, 50, 50, "My Button");
        button.Text = "My Button";
        button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
     }

     void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("I was clicked!");
     }
```

You could also add controls dynamically to documents via a VSTO add-in, using code along these lines (thanks to people on the [VSTO forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fcadefb-49e2-4f05-8b73-8aabce8dc40d/can-i-add-controls-dynamically-to-a-worksheet-via-a-vsto-addin?forum=vsto) for that one):

```
var workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet) sheet;
var vstoSheet = workSheet.GetVstoObject();
var button = vstoSheet.Controls.AddButton(50, 50, 100, 50, "Test");
button.Text = "Dynamic Button!";
```

Check [this post by Eric Carter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/eric_carter/using-vsto-document-features-in-application-level-add-ins) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code which works for me in VSTO Add-in (modified version of Mathias's answer):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using ExcelTools = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;

public void AddButtonToWorksheet()
{
  Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
  ExcelTools.Worksheet vstoSheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(worksheet);

  Button button = new Button();
  button.Text = "Dynamic Button!";
  vstoSheet.Controls.AddControl(
    button, 50, 50, 100, 50, "TestButton");
}
```