# How to have cancel button on UI in long running task in VSTO Addin?

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading, vsto

I created an Excel Addin in c# that goes through a couple 1000 rows and performs some updates on the cells. It is very long running and I would like the user the option to CANCEL if need be.

As it is by default the UI is not responsive during the processing.

Is there something in the Excel Addin framework for this ? Do I create a new thread?  Would that cause issues with the ability to update the UI thread though?

Looking for some general direction or links to something to get me started.

EDIT: The example given is for creating a simple button click event. I understand that.  I need to CANCEL a process within VSTO  which is more complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding buttons to spreadsheets in .NET (VSTO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046032/adding-buttons-to-spreadsheets-in-net-vsto)

Comment: There is very little on VSTO addins and I have searched sir. It seems like a common situation but I could not find anything and have trouble understand how multithreading works in regard to the UI thread/ main thread

Comment: have you checked the Link that I posted it seems to be rather similar in nature to what you are trying to do..?

Comment: Yes read it twice. It is not related to what I am asking.

Comment: well perhaps you can show some existing code so that one can see the difference between what you are doing vs the code / answer in the posted link.. don't you think..?

Comment: I don't have existing code since I am not sure what the correct way is to handle long running processes inside an Action Pane and how to allow the user to cancel it. That is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies not with the Excel Object Model or the VSTO framework, but rather in .NET.  All you need is a BackgroundWorker class, which will automatically leverage multi-threading and easily facilitates cancelling the operation.  Here's a good article that can get you started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke.aspx

Comment: Ok. But to update the UI as each row is process in that separate task isn't there something tricky about that? I thought I recall needing something like..Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(()

Comment: I'm not sure - let me know how it behaves